# Trying to include a header with its own CSS in several pages

Tags: html, css

I made a header for various parts of my website, all of which run on different software (mediawiki, phpbb, regular html, etc.). I want it to be the absolute top of every page.

What would be the easiest way to include it in whichever pages I would want, and how can I include its CSS attributes without conflicting with other elements of the same type? I tried both classes and IDs to no avail. For example, keeping these ul and li CSS attributes without having a conflict with ul and li elements that are already on a given page.

Here's the code, CSS included:

```
<head>
<style>
* {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
body {
    font-family: Tahoma;
}
a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #ffffff;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-family: Tahoma;
}
ul {
    display: inline;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
ul li {
    list-style: none;
    display: inline;
    margin-left: 6px;
    margin-right: 6px;
    padding-left: 3px;
    padding-right: 3px;
    padding-top: 3px;
    border-bottom: 3px solid #34549F;
}
ul li:hover {
    background-color: #7FBCF9;
    border-bottom: #ffffff;
    color: #000000;
    border-bottom: 3px solid #ffffff;
    color: black;
}
#fullNav {
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
    border-bottom: 2px solid;
    background-color: #34549F;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="fullNav">
<ul>
    <li><a href="foo">foo</a></li>
    <li><a href="foo2">foo2</a></li>
    <li><a href="foo3">foo3</a></li>
    <li><a href="foo4">foo4</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: so whats the question? How to include this in everything? Or what? Please clarify...

Comment: The easiest method to include it in anything I want, and a way to keep its CSS attributes separate from the main page it is included in.

Answer (score 2):

It seems you have a little quagmire from not planning the implementation all that well. I'm going to assume you have PHP on your server because you are running phpBB.

I would think the easiest way to include the code is to edit the templates for each of your different softwares, and `include("example.php")` or `require("example.php")` the template all from the same place.

In your PHP file you can create the template for the header

```
    <? function makeHeader(){
     /* header html which only includes <div>, etc and 
      not the full html required to generate a page layout. */
      <div id="fullNav">
<ul >
    <li ><a href="foo">foo</a></li>
    <li ><a href="foo2">foo2</a></li>
    <li ><a href="foo3">foo3</a></li>
    <li ><a href="foo4">foo4</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
    }
    ?>
```

And in your various HTML templates, you can call it using `<? makeHeader() ?>` which will bring in your HTML.

The CSS for your header should be bundled all together, then can also be referenced from one place for the entire site using:
`<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="example.css" />`

To avoid CSS name collisions, use unique names for the id and classes for the headers. So instead of `#header`, you can use something like `#AndreisGlobalHeader`. It isn't foolproof, but it should save you the time of having to go through the existing CSS looking for a collision. Also using `class` and `id` in your CSS for the links will help eliminate any problems.